# EJB, JPA business method into entity

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, entity

i have got uml diagram from projectant and into entity i have got method getTotalPrice()

So this is my class:

```
public class UOrder {

   @OneToMany
   private List<Product> products;

   ....
   public BigDecimal getTotalPrice(){
   BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(0.0);
   for(Product p : products){
   b.add(p.getPrice());
   }
   return b;

 }

}
```

**It is good idea to do it like that ? logical busines into entity ?** 
I have got only function in uml diagram not field totalPrice or something like that so i figure out that it must be like that ...

Answer (score 2):

It's more like a matter of taste. For example, if you like [Domain Driven Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) philosophy it's a really good idea as the total price belongs to the `UOrder` class.

Answer (score 0):

I think isn't bad, but I preferrer like (pseudo code):

```
public class UOrder {
    ...
    public BigDecimal getTotalPrice() {
        return PriceUtil.getTotalPrice(products);
    }
}

public class PriceUtil {
    public static BigDecimal getTotalPrice(List<Product> products) {
        return sum-of-products;
    }
    ... other userful and fancy price functions ...
}
```

because you usually need:

- to calcuate VAT or
- price of other class as Product or
- price in other class as UOrder
- and so on.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate point of view (an active record style data mapping object is just the persisted data in a handy form - a value object), here's what I think:

Given that you've said that the method *is* business logic, and given the well known domain that @Anton talks about - it's a bad idea. If you *hadn't* said it was business logic, I'd have questioned why you cared about that total in your application.

As an experiment, consider re-naming your mapped class UOrderData, treat it as a value object, and have a UOrder class that implements the business logic at application level.